# Can I use a pointer to point to multiple sections of an array at once?

Tags: arrays, pointers, fortran

In the work I'm doing, I declare an array with some length *N*.

At some point during my code, the data between certain elements needs to be removed.

If my initial array is [1,2,3,4,5], I want to change it to [1,2,4,5]. But I don't just do it once. The process will involved removing each element until there are no elements left and I may take out more than one element at once. The reason why I do this is related a complicated process I'm trying to reproduce and I don't think its necessary to go into this right now.

What I want to be able to do is define an array

```
a = (/ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 /)
```

and if I decided to remove elements 3 and 4 I could set up a pointer (call it *p*) such that it would point to *a* as:

```
p = (/ 1, 2, 5 /)
```

Specifically, *p* will have length that is equal to *a* minus the number of elements removed. I'd want to do this morn than once. Redefine *a*

```
a = (/ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 /)
```

First I remove elements 4 and 5 and point to it such that

```
p = (/ 1, 2, 3, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 /)
```

And then later removed 7,8,9 I could point to *a*

```
p = (/ 1, 2, 3, 6, 10 /)
```

Meanwhile keeping *a* intact. The *p* above would in my head be created by pointing to the first three elements of *a* and then the 6th and then the 10th all at once in one compact pointer.

I know I can probably achieve the same results with allocatable arrays, but I see pointers as being extremely useful.

Answer (score 1):

No.  An array pointer can be associated any array section, but not arbitrary elements.

Depending on what you later want to do, you can have a second array that lists the current indices in `a`, and then use vector subscripting for certain operations.  But there are limitations for where a vector subscripted array can be used (e.g. if associated with a dummy argument it cannot be redefined), and in some cases the underlying implementation of a vector subscripted array may simply be to create a temporary contiguous copy of the relevant elements anyway.

Answer (score 1):

I usually approach it using an allocatable (data) array, and also another logical array that is a mask for the data array. Then use the mask to keep track of what elements of the array are 'in use' or 'not in use'. When the need arises the active or 'in use' elements can be packed into either a final or intermediate array and if it is intermediate then the logical array reset to the size of the new data array.

And I generally avoid pointers.

PACK https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gfortran/PACK.html and SUM(logical array) may be useful here.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on whether the access speed to an arbitrary position in the array is more important than the speed of erasing elements.
If erasing elements is your priority, you should definitely make a linked list structure in which you are able to erase n elements at once.
If, on the other hand, what you need is access speed to the data you should use an array.